# Set field to automatically insert time-stamp on UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table with a *DEC* field named `product_price` and I wanted to add a field called `price_updated_date`. Is there a way to set the table to automatically insert the current time-stamp whenever the `product_price` field has been updated?

If not, is there a way to set it to insert the current time-stamp any time the entry is updated at all?

### update:

It seems like using a trigger is the best option here. I am new to triggers and having some trouble creating it. Here is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER price_update
AFTER UPDATE ON cart_product
FOR EACH ROW
IF(OLD.product_price != NEW.product_price)
THEN
UPDATE cart_product 
SET price_updated_date = CURDATE()
WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id
```

This is giving me this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yup, create trigger after update on your table

`CREATE TRIGGER price_update AFTER UPDATE on _table_ FOR EACH ROW UPDATE _table_  SET price_updated_date = CURTIME() where id=NEW.id`

Comment: This will only update the row I am changing right? This will run if I change any field in the row.. is it possible to only run when I change product_price? Thanks!

Comment: Yup, modify FOR EACH ROW by adding IF THEN construction (IF OLD.product_price!=NEW.product_price) THEN _run_update_code

Comment: Thank you, I am getting an error trying to create this trigger, I added my code to my question. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

Comment: @John Isaacks add END; TO end of your trigger create sql

Answer (score 14):

Why not set properties for that field as:

```
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: One reason would be if you don't want the server timestamp but rather something like UTC.

Comment: Because the row could have several fields and one wants to get the update time when one specific field is updated only.

Answer (score 3):

I note you're using MySQL

The default behaviour of a MySQL timestamp field is to default to NOW() on insert AND on update

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html

I know this isn't dependant on which column has been updated as you require, but may be of some use to you or someone else browsing this question.

Its a 5-second job - just add a timestamp field & hey presto

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you run an update statement, make sure you do something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET `product_price` = 'whatever', price_updated_date = NOW()
```

This will always insert the current date/time when you change the row.

Comment: A trigger (or stored procedure instead of direct access to table) is the only way to enforce this regardless of the client/program used to access the database. I prefer this instead of asking every developer to "make sure you always do X".

Answer (score -2):

Use a database trigger:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html