# MySQL trigger update timestamp for doc if its keywords change

Tags: mysql, triggers

Based on this:

[Set field to automatically insert time-stamp on UPDATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246971/set-field-to-automatically-insert-time-stamp-on-update)

I am trying to create a trigger that suits my need, but I see an inconvenient using OLD and NEW keywords.

I have 2 tables related, `documents` and `keywords`. `Documents` can have many keywords and keywords must have one document.

I am able to edit keywords through a GUI, and if I change a `keyword`, the `Document.update_time` should be changed with `current_timestamp()`

How can I link an event in `keywords` table to trigger an update in `document.update_time`?

```
CREATE TRIGGER document_update
AFTER UPDATE ON keywords
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF(OLD.value != NEW.value)
THEN
UPDATE documents 
SET documents.update_time = current_timestamp()
WHERE documents.id = NEW.document_fk_id
END
```

But for `documents` I have a similar trigger.

Is it possible to instead of repeating triggers code, that `keywords' trigger` forwards a call to `documents trigger`? Or should I repeat the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER keywords_updae  AFTER UPDATE ON keywords 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE document SET document.update_time= NOW() 
WHERE documents.id = OLD.id AND documents.value != OLD.value;
END;
|
```

Comment: Thanks, can I forward a trigger to another trigger instead of repeating the code for the `documents` update trigger?