# How to edit mysql table to auto enable created_at and updated_at fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table consisting of created_at and updated_at fields. I've already created the table without enabling default values.
How do I make the 'created_at' field record the datetime of creation(writing will occur only once at time of creation) and 'updated_at' field to fill in the datetime of the moment of the table update.

Comment: You forgot to share the code of your current attempts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set field to automatically insert time-stamp on UPDATE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246971/set-field-to-automatically-insert-time-stamp-on-update)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create trigger is good solution, but this is for me better

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`
ADD `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
ADD `updated_at` timestamp NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER `created_at`;
```

Comment: This will create a new column named created_at and updated_at. I already have those, just want to add the property to those columns. Can you help me in that?